# iOS 9 App localization

Tags: ios, swift, app-store, ios9

I'm working on a "cook book" app that has multiple (language) versions.
Apple says I can't upload multiple apps that are almost the same, so how can I achieve what is mentioned below in single app release ?

1. multiple languages (possible)
2. multiple logos (possible)
3. different "config" file for each language - e.g. file with API URLs
4. Each language version "separately" on App store so a user can download both english and spanish versions

My biggest problem is #4, it has to be possible that one can decide which language version he downloads.

Comment: that isn't possible. the way app store works is that the app translates the text based on the user locale and not on user downloading separate app for different language.

Answer (score 0):

You're most likely still looking at one app with multiple languages included in it, which are picked based on user local. If you want the user to decide which language they'd like after install, give them an option. Many apps do this already.

Comment: I think I'll do something similar what you mentioned as it seems to be imposible to have installed both version at the same time

Answer (score 0):

I think you can follow these steps to create the app you'd like to make.

1. Localize your application. (This [tutorial](https://www.raywenderlich.com/64401/internationalization-tutorial-for-ios-2014) might be useful.)
2. Add a `language` parameter to your API calls and return the data based on the language parameter. Thus you won't be displaying a content which is not available in that language.
3. For your 4th requirement if you'd like to use versioning on each language (I do not know why but if you must) then you can use the `language` paramter you'll add on API calls. Just create a releation between the languages and the versions you are using then display the views and contents based on the relation.